# Wirecloud FI-Ware Testbed compatibility

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I was wondering if Wirecloud offers complete support for object storage with FI-WARE Testbed instead of Fi-lab. I have successfully integrated Wirecloud with Testbed and have developed a set of widgets that are able to upload/download files to specific containers in Fi-lab with success. However, the same widgets do not seem to work in Fi-lab, as i get an error 500 when trying to retrieve the auth tokens (also with the well known object-storage-test widget) containing the following response:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at create (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/controllers/Token.js:343:25)
    at callbacks (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:195:15)
    at Object.handle (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/server.js:31:5)
    at next (/home/fiware/fi-ware-keystone-proxy/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:195:15)
```

I noticed that the token provided in the beggining (to start the transaction) is

```
token: Object
id: "%fiware_token%"
```

Any idea regarding what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WireCloud instance available at FI-WARE's testbed is always the latest stable version while the FI-LAB instance is currently outdated, we're working on updating it as soon as possible. One of the things that changes between those versions is the Object Storage API, so sorry for the inconvenience as you will not be able to use widgets/operators using the Object Storage in both environments.

Anyway, the response you were obtaining seems to indicate the object storage instance you are accessing is not working properly, so you will need to send an email to one of the available mail lists for getting help (fiware-testbed-help or fiware-lab-help) telling what is happening to you (remember to include your account information as there are several object storage nodes and ones can be up and the others down).

Regarding the strange request body:

```json
"token": {
    id: "%fiware_token%"
}
```

This behaviour is normal, as the WireCloud client code has no direct access to the IdM token of the user. It's the WireCloud's proxy which replaces the `%fiware_token%` pattern with the correct value.

Comment: I think you meant the opposite when referring to FI-LAB and Testbed; FI-LAB should be the most updated one, not vice-versa. I am telling this because i have successfully tested the Object Storage functionality in FI-LAB, the problem relies on Testbed integration (which does not offer multiple regions as well).

Regarding the functionality of the ObjectStorage instance of Testbed, i also assume this should be a matter of API since i can properly create containers/files through the portal.

Anyway, thank you for your time answering my question!

Comment: @Artem No, I don't mean the opposite :-(. Currently, the WireCloud instance found at FI-Lab is older than the instance found at the FI-WARE testbed.

Comment: Oh, I see. That was totally unexpected!! :D
Anyhow, i am using my own wirecloud instance so this should make no difference. It's just that this instance is located in a VM in Testbed. Thank you for your time anyway!